# Eloquent simplify / combine query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to simplify the following query. I have a meter and a relation (+ or -) and I would like to sum date-ranges based on the meter criteria. The positive meters should be summed up and the negative ones subtracted from the sum. As showed below, I split the meter array into two arrays ($meter_plus, $meter_minus) with ids only, both for sum values, but $meter_minus should be subtracted.

// Edit: Fetching meters

```
$begin = new \DateTime($from);
$end = new \DateTime($to);
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
// find points and meters by group
$grouping = App\Grouping::with('points.meters')->find($group_id);
$meter_plus = [];
$meter_minus = [];
// each group has one-to-many points, each point has one-to-many meters
foreach($grouping->points as $point) {
    foreach($point->meters as $meter) {
        if($meter->Relation == '+') {
            array_push($meter_plus, $meter);
        } else {
            array_push($meter_minus, $meter);
        }
    }
}
```

// Edit2: Point - Meter relation

```
public function meters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\EnergyMeter', 'meteringpoint_energymeter_relation', 'point_id', 'meter_id')
        ->whereHas('users', function ($q) {
            $q->where('UserID', Auth::id());
        })
        ->where('Deleted', 0)
        ->select('*', 'meteringpoint_energymeter_relation.Relation')
        ->orderBy('EMNumber');
}
```

--

```
$plus = Data::selectRaw('sum(values) as data')
    ->where('PointOfTime', '>', $begin->format('U'))
    ->where('PointOfTime', '<=', $end->format('U'))
    ->whereIn('meter_id', collect($meter_plus)->lists('id'))
    ->first();

$minus = Data::selectRaw('sum(values) as data')
    ->where('PointOfTime', '>', $begin->format('U'))
    ->where('PointOfTime', '<=', $end->format('U'))
    ->whereIn('meter_id', collect($meter_minus)->lists('id'))
    ->first();

$data = $plus->data - $minus->data
```

This works fine but I would like to

1. improve the query
2. calculate the final sum in query

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereBetween` for your `PointOfTime` range and `sum` instead of `selectRaw`. Also, if `$meter_plus` is already an array of just the id's, you don't need to do whatever it is you're doing with `collect`. You might also want to indicate a table to query.

```
$plus = Data::table('some_table')
    ->sum('values')
    ->whereBetween('PointOfTime',array($begin->format('U'), $end->format('U')))
    ->whereIn('meter_id', $meter_plus)
    ->sum('values')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I got an array of meters that are mixed in the first place. I split them in $meter_plus and $meter_minus to retrieve the data anyway. So, I've created to new arrays and converted them with collect([..]) http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections to use the ->lists() method. I'm interested in the sum of the result of the plus and minus data, so you are suggesting ->get(), this will return an array, am I correct?

Comment: No. If you want both sums in one query, you would need to use something like group by, but that would probably be better done in the original query that retrieves the meter_I'd array.

Comment: I've added some information, maybe they are helpful to you :)